# how to update by IdItem

Tags: php, mysql

To master2 in php, mysql. I'm new in php about 2 month

I need help. about update table.

I have page that display current table. when I click update button update, I want row 1, quantity in current table will decrease by IdItem from result table. So the equation will like this in current table quantity=quantity-quantityPass. So only field Item change quantity result. Now when I click update, it effect to all in table current result. any solution?

table for 'result'

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+
| IdItem |  username   |   rentItem   | quantity  | result | quantityPass |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+
| 84     | FahmiNazirul|   Speaker    |     1     | PASS   |      1       |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+
| 86     |     Andy    |   Keyboard   |     3     | PASS   |      2       |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+
| 89     | FahmiNazirul|   Speaker    |     5     | PASS   |      3       |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+
```

table for current quantity 'update'

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+ 
|  Id    |    Item     |    quantity  |
+--------+-------------+--------------+ 
|   1    |   Speaker   |     10       |
+--------+-------------+--------------+ 
|   2    |  Keyboard   |     10       | 
+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

tableupdate.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM update where Item = Item");

                echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Quantiti</th>
                <th></th>       
                </tr>";

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  $item= $row['Item'];

                  echo " <tr> ";
                  echo " <td> " . $row['Item'] . " </td> ";
                  echo " <td> " . $row['quantity'] . " </td> ";

                  echo " </tr> ";
                  }
                echo "</table>";

echo " <a href ='quantityupdate.php?Item=$item'  onclick='return Confirm_Box()' >Update</a>";
```

quantityupdate.php

```
$item =$_REQUEST['Item'];


// sending query


mysql_query("UPDATE update ,result SET update.quantity=update.quantity-result.quantityPass where update.Item = result.rentItem")
or die(mysql_error());      

header("Location: update.php");
```

Comment: does itemID is `auto_increment`. ?

Comment: yes. it auto_increment

Comment: the word update must be back ticked (`) if used in reference.

Comment: UPDATE `update` ? @MarshallHouse okay. I will try it. actualy in my language, It not use word update, but 'kemaskini'. btw thanks

Comment: @FahmiNazirul so it will hard to update it because you might update it with having duplication.

Comment: @DipeshParmar its true, it become duplication. any suggestion to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like this:

```
UPDATE kemaskini AS u
INNER JOIN result AS r ON u.Item = r.rentItem
SET u.quantity = u.quantity - r.quantityPass;
```

---

For the duplicate entries of the `Item` in the first table `result` you can do this:

```
UPDATE kemaskini AS u
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT rentItem, SUM(quantityPass) AS TotalquantityPass
   FROM result
   GROUP BY rentItem
)  AS r ON u.Item = r.rentItem
SET u.quantity = u.quantity - r.TotalquantityPass;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0897/2)

Comment: okay. I will try it. act i didnt use 'update' but i use 'kemaskini' in my language. so I translet to english.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE update ,result SET update.quantity=update.quantity-result.quantityPass where  result.rentItem='$item' AND update.Item='$item'")
```